# Saving hashes of data in Monero blockchain

Tags: block-explorer, metadata

It is possible to store some information in the Monero blockchain that isn't strictly related to a cryptocurrency transaction?

For example, let's say I have a txt file, I calculate its SHA1 hash and then I create a mock transaction (maybe between two wallets which I both control) to insert that hash inside the metadata. Later, when it is confirmed by the network, I can go to some explorer (e.g. https://moneroblocks.info/) and look inside the right block to check it out, and it will stay there forever (at least as long the monero blockchain continues to exist).

I was wondering if a thing like could be applicated, or, because Monero expose very little data -basically only the fee payed to the miners- it's just structurally impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to store arbitrary data in the tx extra field. You'd have to manually construct your tx though (no wallets allow for this) and block explorers will only show the hex data of it, if at all.

Comment: Ok so at the Moment It Is a pretty complex procedure. I'll check how to manually build a transaction.

Comment: "Complicated" because it's not an intended use case. The Monero blockchain is not intended as a *general purpose* database. Things like Ethereum would be better suited.